# Why does my mac keep crashing?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, crash, kernel-panic

(I will have to do this fast, since I think my mac will crash again.)

My Mac keeps crashing. It started happening since I installed Adobe Acrobat Pro (since then I have removed it), but it might be unrelated to that. Even after I removed it, it still keeps crashing every few minutes.

Here is the latest panic log from Console:

> 

```
Sun Jun 15 22:44:53 2014 Machine-check capabilities (cpu 7)
> 0x0000000000000c09:  family: 6 model: 42 stepping: 7 microcode: 26 
> Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-2675QM CPU @ 2.20GHz  9 error-reporting banks 
> threshold-based error status present  extended corrected memory error
> handling present Machine-check status 0x0000000000000004: 
> machine-check in progress MCA error-reporting registers: 
> IA32_MC0_STATUS(0x401): 0x0000000000000000 invalid 
> IA32_MC1_STATUS(0x405): 0x0980000000000000 invalid 
> IA32_MC2_STATUS(0x409): 0x0000000000000000 invalid 
> IA32_MC3_STATUS(0x40d): 0xfe00000000800400 valid   MCA error code:    
> 0x0400   Model specific error code: 0x0080   Other information:       
> 0x00000000   Threshold-based status:    Undefined   Status bits:   
> Processor context corrupt    ADDR register valid    MISC register
> valid    Error enabled    Uncorrected error    Error overflow 
> IA32_MC3_ADDR(0x40e): 0x00003f7f817522f5  IA32_MC3_MISC(0x40f):
> 0x000000000003ffff  IA32_MC4_STATUS(0x411): 0x0000000000000000 invalid
> IA32_MC5_STATUS(0x415): 0x0020000000000000 invalid 
> IA32_MC6_STATUS(0x419): 0x0020000000000000 invalid 
> IA32_MC7_STATUS(0x41d): 0x0020000000000000 invalid  Package 0 logged: 
> IA32_MC8_STATUS(0x421): 0x0020000000000000 invalid panic(cpu 1 caller
> 0xffffff80002c4dd5): "Machine Check at 0xffffff7f81dd9c7f,
> registers:\n" "CR0: 0x000000008001003b, CR2: 0x00007f809bc00000, CR3:
> 0x0000000000100000, CR4: 0x00000000000606e0\n" "RAX:
> 0x0000000000000031, RBX: 0x0000000000000000, RCX: 0x0000000000000001,
> RDX: 0x0000000000000000\n" "RSP: 0xffffff80e842bd80, RBP:
> 0xffffff80e842bdb0, RSI: 0x0000000000000007, RDI:
> 0xffffff8011ea2400\n" "R8:  0xffffff8011d5a800, R9: 
> 0x0000000000000000, R10: 0x8000000000100000, R11:
> 0xffffff80002dad00\n" "R12: 0x00000000000008f8, R13:
> 0xffffff8011c29940, R14: 0xffffff8011d5a800, R15:
> 0x0000000000000007\n" "RFL: 0x0000000000000046, RIP:
> 0xffffff7f81dd9c7f, CS:  0x0000000000000008, SS: 
> 0x0000000000000010\n" "Error code:
> 0x0000000000000000\n"@/SourceCache/xnu/xnu-1699.32.7/osfmk/i386/trap_native.c:278
> Backtrace (CPU 1), Frame : Return Address 0xffffff80e84bcec0 :
> 0xffffff8000220792  0xffffff80e84bcf40 : 0xffffff80002c4dd5 
> 0xffffff80e84bd0a0 : 0xffffff80002daf2f  0xffffff80e842bdb0 :
> 0xffffff7f81dc7f65  0xffffff80e842be80 : 0xffffff7f81dc9a5c 
> 0xffffff80e842bf30 : 0xffffff80002c6422  0xffffff80e842bf50 :
> 0xffffff800022d375  0xffffff80e842bf90 : 0xffffff800022ccdb 
> 0xffffff80e842bfb0 : 0xffffff8000820057 
>       Kernel Extensions in backtrace:
>          com.apple.driver.AppleIntelCPUPowerManagement(195.0)[70D39B65-894A-335D-A051-0C8B8CAFEA82]@0xffffff7f81dc6000->0xffffff7f81deefff
> 
> BSD process name corresponding to current thread: kernel_task
> 
> Mac OS version: 11G63
> 
> Kernel version: Darwin Kernel Version 11.4.2: Thu Aug 23 16:25:48 PDT
> 2012; root:xnu-1699.32.7~1/RELEASE_X86_64 Kernel UUID:
> FF3BB088-60A4-349C-92EA-CA649C698CE5 System model name: MacBookPro8,2
> (Mac-94245A3940C91C80)
> 
> System uptime in nanoseconds: 106689630414 last loaded kext at
> 46405102669: com.apple.driver.AppleHWSensor   1.9.5d0 (addr
> 0xffffff7f81df0000, size 28672) loaded kexts:
> org.openafs.filesystems.afs   1.6.5
> com.apple.driver.AppleHWSensor    1.9.5d0
> com.apple.filesystems.autofs  3.0 com.apple.driver.AudioAUUC  1.59
> com.apple.driver.AppleTyMCEDriver 1.0.2d2
> com.apple.driver.AGPM 100.12.75
> com.apple.driver.AppleMikeyHIDDriver  122
> com.apple.driver.AppleHDAHardwareConfigDriver 2.2.5a5
> com.apple.driver.AppleHDA 2.2.5a5
> com.apple.driver.AppleMikeyDriver 2.2.5a5
> com.apple.driver.AppleUpstreamUserClient  3.5.9
> com.apple.kext.ATIFramebuffer 7.3.2
> com.apple.driver.AppleIntelHD3000Graphics 7.3.2
> com.apple.driver.SMCMotionSensor  3.0.2d6
> com.apple.driver.AppleSMCPDRC 5.0.0d8
> com.apple.iokit.IOUserEthernet    1.0.0d1
> com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothSerialManager  4.0.8f17
> com.apple.driver.AppleSMCLMU  2.0.1d2
> com.apple.Dont_Steal_Mac_OS_X 7.0.0
> com.apple.driver.AudioIPCDriver   1.2.3
> com.apple.driver.ApplePolicyControl   3.1.33
> com.apple.driver.ACPI_SMC_PlatformPlugin  5.0.0d8
> com.apple.driver.AppleMuxControl  3.1.33
> com.apple.driver.AppleLPC 1.6.0 com.apple.ATIRadeonX3000  7.3.2
> com.apple.driver.AppleBacklight   170.2.2
> com.apple.driver.AppleMCCSControl 1.0.33
> com.apple.driver.BroadcomUSBBluetoothHCIController    4.0.8f17
> com.apple.driver.AppleUSBTCButtons    227.6
> com.apple.driver.AppleUSBTCKeyEventDriver 227.6
> com.apple.driver.AppleIRController    312
> com.apple.driver.AppleUSBTCKeyboard   227.6
> com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeDataless   1.0.0d1
> com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeZlib   1.0.0d1
> com.apple.BootCache   33 com.apple.iokit.SCSITaskUserClient   3.2.1
> com.apple.driver.XsanFilter   404
> com.apple.iokit.IOAHCISerialATAPI 2.0.3
> com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIBlockStorage    2.1.0
> com.apple.driver.AppleUSBHub  5.1.0 com.apple.driver.AppleFWOHCI  4.9.0
> com.apple.driver.AirPort.Brcm4331 561.7.22
> com.apple.driver.AppleSDXC    1.2.2
> com.apple.iokit.AppleBCM5701Ethernet  3.2.4b8
> com.apple.driver.AppleEFINVRAM    1.6.1
> com.apple.driver.AppleSmartBatteryManager 161.0.0
> com.apple.driver.AppleAHCIPort    2.3.1
> com.apple.driver.AppleUSBEHCI 5.1.0
> com.apple.driver.AppleUSBUHCI 5.1.0
> com.apple.driver.AppleACPIButtons 1.5 com.apple.driver.AppleRTC   1.5
> com.apple.driver.AppleHPET    1.7 com.apple.driver.AppleSMBIOS    1.9
> com.apple.driver.AppleACPIEC  1.5 com.apple.driver.AppleAPIC  1.6
> com.apple.driver.AppleIntelCPUPowerManagementClient   195.0.0
> com.apple.nke.applicationfirewall 3.2.30
> com.apple.security.quarantine 1.4 com.apple.security.TMSafetyNet  8
> com.apple.driver.AppleIntelCPUPowerManagement 195.0.0
> com.apple.kext.triggers   1.0 com.apple.driver.DspFuncLib 2.2.5a5
> com.apple.iokit.IOFireWireIP  2.2.5 com.apple.iokit.IOSurface 80.0.2
> com.apple.iokit.IOSerialFamily    10.0.5
> com.apple.driver.AppleHDAController   2.2.5a5
> com.apple.iokit.IOHDAFamily   2.2.5a5
> com.apple.iokit.IOAudioFamily 1.8.6fc18
> com.apple.kext.OSvKernDSPLib  1.3 com.apple.driver.AppleSMC   3.1.3d10
> com.apple.driver.IOPlatformPluginLegacy   5.0.0d8
> com.apple.driver.AppleSMBusPCI    1.0.10d0
> com.apple.driver.AppleGraphicsControl 3.1.33
> com.apple.driver.IOPlatformPluginFamily   5.1.1d6
> com.apple.driver.AppleBacklightExpert 1.0.4
> com.apple.iokit.IONDRVSupport 2.3.4
> com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltEDMSink  1.1.8
> com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltEDMSource    1.1.8
> com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPOutAdapter 1.8.5
> com.apple.driver.AppleSMBusController 1.0.10d0
> com.apple.kext.ATI6000Controller  7.3.2 com.apple.kext.ATISupport 7.3.2
> com.apple.driver.AppleIntelSNBGraphicsFB  7.3.2
> com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily  2.3.4
> com.apple.driver.AppleFileSystemDriver    13
> com.apple.driver.AppleUSBBluetoothHCIController   4.0.8f17
> com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothFamily 4.0.8f17
> com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPInAdapter  1.8.5
> com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPAdapterFamily  1.8.5
> com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltPCIDownAdapter   1.2.5
> com.apple.driver.AppleUSBMultitouch   230.5
> com.apple.iokit.IOUSBHIDDriver    5.0.0
> com.apple.driver.AppleUSBMergeNub 5.1.0
> com.apple.driver.AppleUSBComposite    5.0.0
> com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIMultimediaCommandsDevice    3.2.1
> com.apple.iokit.IOBDStorageFamily 1.7
> com.apple.iokit.IODVDStorageFamily    1.7.1
> com.apple.iokit.IOCDStorageFamily 1.7.1
> com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIArchitectureModelFamily 3.2.1
> com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltNHI  1.6.0
> com.apple.iokit.IOThunderboltFamily   2.0.3
> com.apple.iokit.IOUSBUserClient   5.0.0
> com.apple.iokit.IOFireWireFamily  4.4.8
> com.apple.iokit.IO80211Family 420.3
> com.apple.iokit.IOEthernetAVBController   1.0.1b1
> com.apple.iokit.IONetworkingFamily    2.1
> com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIFamily  2.0.8 com.apple.iokit.IOUSBFamily   5.1.0
> com.apple.driver.AppleEFIRuntime  1.6.1
> com.apple.iokit.IOHIDFamily   1.7.1 com.apple.iokit.IOSMBusFamily 1.1
> com.apple.security.sandbox    177.11 com.apple.kext.AppleMatch    1.0.0d1
> com.apple.driver.DiskImages   331.7
> com.apple.iokit.IOStorageFamily   1.7.2
> com.apple.driver.AppleKeyStore    28.18
> com.apple.driver.AppleACPIPlatform    1.5 com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily 2.7
> com.apple.iokit.IOACPIFamily  1.4
```

Comment: Could you tell us which Adobe exactly. It might have installed a driver that is causing the problem. http://helpx.adobe.com/x-productkb/policy-pricing/system-requirements-acrobat-family-products.html

Answer (score 1):

Steps to verify or repair Kernel Panic (KP):

Boot into safe mode (restart holding down SHIFT key).

- If **no** KP, then some 3rd-party thing is causing the problem.
- If **yes** KP, then most likely hardware related.

  - Run the [Apple Hardware Test suite](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht1509), extended tests at least twice

> Using Apple Hardware Test on computers with OS X 10.7 or later   Mac
>   NoteBook and Desktop computers shipping with OS X 10.7 or later have a
>   partition on the hard drive or flash storage that contains AHT. To
>   start AHT on these computers please follow these instructions:
>
> - Press the power button to turn on your computer.
> - Press and hold the D key before the gray startup screen appears.
>
> It takes a minute or so for AHT to start up and inspect your hardware configuration. While this is taking place, an icon appears on
>   the screen:
>
> When the process is complete, select your language and click the right arrow. If you aren't using a mouse, you can use the up and down
>   arrows to select a language and then press the Return key.
>
> ```
> The AHT console appears. You can choose which sort of test or tests to perform:
> ```
>
> - To perform all of the basic tests, click the Test button or press the "T" key or the Return key.
> - To perform a more thorough diagnostic test, select the "Perform extended testing" checkbox under the Test button before you
>     click the Test button.
>
>   Note: Your test results will appear in the window in the bottom-right of the console.
>     To exit AHT, click Restart or Shut Down at the bottom of the window.